# Static Pages not working for certain Wordpress themes

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I tried to use Newsmag PRO and Vmag Lite themes and everything seemed perfect for **mydomain.com/home**, when I set *home* page as static page in Admin Panel, then **mydomain.com** became a blank page or sometimes only menu appeared.
After hours searching, I gave up and downgraded to Newsmag Lite version and everything is fine, I mean now **mydomain.com/home** is equal to **mydomain.com**.

Does anyone have a clue of what can possibly happened? This lite version have less resources, I need to upgrade again for my website look how I wanted to.

---

Comment: one time try to change permalink

Comment: Thanks @SureshSuthar! Maybe this works, but still something is missing because themes documentation guides us to create a home page, then set as static page in Settings -> Read in Admin Panel. What I just said shouldn't be happening.

Answer (score 0):

Some time problem in ht-access so try to change permalink some time it's work

And check your selected template,have some any error in template then show black page there